Volume under $z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ and above the region in the first quadrant with $r=\sin{\theta}$
The region
As the question states, I’m attempting to find the volume under $z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ and above $r=\sin{\theta}$. The problem is that I want to do this in spherical coordinates. Using cylindrical coordinates, the integral is trivially
$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\sin{\theta}}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}rdzdrd\theta=\frac{3\pi-4}{18}$.
When I try to set this up using spherical coordinates, it doesn’t give me the same answer.
I have $z^2=1-r^2$, so $\rho^2\cos^2{\phi}=1-\rho^2\sin^2{\phi} \implies \rho = 1$.
Also,
$r=\sin{\theta} \implies \rho\sin{\phi}=\sin{\theta} \implies \sin{\phi}=\sin{\theta}$
if $\rho=1$, meaning that ${\phi}={\theta}$.
Additionally, since $r=\sin{\theta}$, then $z=\sqrt{1-r^2}=\sqrt{1-\sin^2{\theta}}=\cos{\theta} \implies$
$\rho\cos{\phi}=\cos{\theta} \implies \rho=\sec{\phi}\cos{\theta}$.
So, I’m setting up
$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\theta}\int_{\sec{\phi}\cos{\theta}}^{1}\rho^2\sin{\phi}d\rho d\phi d\theta$.
The issue is that this doesn’t give me the same answer as the cylindrical coordinate integral. What am I doing wrong?

In spherical coordinates, $x^2+y^2+z^2=\rho^2$, and hence your derivation $\rho=1$ is incorrect. Carefully replace $x$, $y$ and $z$ by their spherical counterparts, and you'll be able to derive the integration boundaries properly.

If I have $r=\sin{\theta}$, then $\rho\sin{\phi}=\sin{\theta}$ and so $\rho=\sin{\theta}\csc{\phi}$. Also, if $z=\sqrt{1-r^2}$, then $\rho\cos{\phi}=\sqrt{1-\sin^2{\theta}}=\cos{\theta}$, so $\rho=\cos{\theta}\sec{\phi}$? Are the bounds I had for $\phi$ and $\theta$ correct?

I tried plugging the above into Maxima, and I got a divergent integral.

A minor point about wording: exactly as asked, the answer is an easy "$0$". as $r=\sin \theta$ is just a simple curve in the plane, the section of the sphere above it is a simple surface in space. Such a surface has no thickness, and no volume. You actually want the volume above the region $r \le \sin \theta$.

Look at your figure. For every point on the surface, there is a line segment back to the origin that lies entirely inside the figure. So regardless of the values of $\theta$ and $\phi$, the lower limit for $\rho$ will always be $0$. The upper limit of $\rho$ will depend on the direction. When the direction exits the sphere for a point with $r\le \sin\theta$, the upper limit on $\rho$ will be $1$, where it exits the sphere. When the direction exits the sphere for a point with $r > \sin\theta$, the upper limit on $\rho$ is the intersection of the ray with the surface $r = \sin\theta$.

Thanks for the explanation!

Let us first rewrite the boundaries of the region in spherical coordinates:
\begin{align}
0\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}&\Rightarrow 0\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}\\
z\geq 0 &\Rightarrow 0\leq\phi\leq\frac{\pi}{2} \\
r\geq 0 &\Rightarrow \rho\geq 0\\
z=\rho\cos\phi\leq \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}=\sqrt{1-\rho^2\sin^2\phi} &\Rightarrow \rho\leq 1\\
r=\rho\sin\phi\leq\sin\theta &\Rightarrow \rho\leq\frac{\sin\theta}{\sin\phi} 
\end{align}
Hence, $\rho\leq\min\{\frac{\sin\theta}{\sin\phi},1\}$. Note that
\begin{align}
\frac{\sin\theta}{\sin\phi}\leq 1\Rightarrow \sin\theta\leq\sin\phi \Rightarrow \theta\leq\arcsin\big(\sin(\phi)\big) =\phi
\end{align}
where the last equality holds because both $\theta,\phi$ are restricted to $[0,\pi/2]$, and thus we can divide the region $\mathcal{R}$ in two parts:
\begin{align}
\mathcal{R}_1&=\Big\{(\rho,\theta,\phi): 0\leq\phi\leq\frac{\pi}{2}\,, 0\leq\theta\leq\phi\,,0\leq\rho\leq\frac{\sin\theta}{\sin\phi}\Big\}\,\,,\\
\mathcal{R}_2&=\Big\{(\rho,\theta, \phi): 0\leq\phi\leq\frac{\pi}{2}\,, \phi\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}\,,0\leq\rho\leq1\Big\}
\\
\end{align}
and we can separate the integral as follows:
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathcal{R}}\,dV &= \int_{\mathcal{R}_1}\,dV+\int_{\mathcal{R}_2}\,dV\\
&=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\phi}\int_{0}^{\sin\theta/\sin\phi}\rho\sin^2\phi\,d\rho d\theta d\phi + \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{\phi}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{1}\rho\sin^2\phi\,d\rho d\theta d\phi\\
&=\frac{1}{9} + \frac{\pi-2}{6} = \frac{3\pi-4}{18}\,.
\end{align}
Note that we obtain the same result if we use OP's region boundary $\rho=\sec\phi \cos\theta$, thanks to $\theta,\phi\in[0,\pi/2]$.

Thank you very much!
